# Multidimensional array sorting in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

One of my function return this array... Yes I have seen other examples here on SO but non where able to solve my problem.

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'refferrer' => string 'http://google.com/' (length=18)
      'number_of_reffers' => string '15' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'refferrer' => string 'https://facebook.com/' (length=21)
      'number_of_reffers' => string '22' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'refferrer' => string 'none' (length=4)
      'number_of_reffers' => string '74' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'refferrer' => string 'http://findy.com/' (length=17)
      'number_of_reffers' => string '6' (length=1)
```

I will like to know how to sort this array in descending and asscending order using the

'number_of_reffers'...

What I am trying to say is that i want the one with the hishest number_of_reffers to come first, follow by the next and so on.

Is this possible and how can i do this in php.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm sure that in other examples you've seen, `usort` has been used. Can you explain why that did not solve your problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have no idea why they were not working, but using the answers below especially the one I accepted explained it better and has also helped me understand [PHP: usort Manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most simplest sense; you may just want to try this:

```
    <?php
        // SORTING ALGORITHM:
        // TO SORT IN THE OPPOSITE SENSE... 
        // (IE. ASCENDING [AS OPPOSED TO THE DEFAULT: DESCENDING]
        // CHANGE THE LESS THAN (<) BELOW TO GREATER THAN (>) 
        function orderByNumRef($arrPrev, $arrNext) {
            if ($arrPrev['number_of_reffers'] == $arrNext['number_of_reffers']) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($arrPrev['number_of_reffers'] < $arrNext['number_of_reffers']) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        //GIVEN ARRAY - DYNAMIC OR HARD-CODED
        $arr = array(
            array(
                'refferrer'         => 'http://google.com/',
                'number_of_reffers' =>'15',
            ),
            array(
                'refferrer'         => 'https://facebook.com/',
                'number_of_reffers' =>'74',
            ),
            array(
                'refferrer'         => 'http://findy.com/',
                'number_of_reffers' =>'6',
            ),
        );


        //BEFORE SORTING:
        var_dump($arr);



        uasort($arr, 'orderByNumRef');

        //AFTER SORTING:
        var_dump($arr);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is awesome... Yes it helped

Answer (score 3):

You need [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Given your array, you would then do this:

```
usort( $array, 'sort_by_referrer_count' );

var_dump($array);

// This will sort ascending
function sort_by_referrer_count( $a, $b ) {
    // Some defensive coding to ensure keys exist
    $a = ( isset( $a['number_of_referrers'] ) ) ? $a['number_of_referrers'] : 0;
    $b = ( isset( $b['number_of_referrers'] ) ) ? $b['number_of_referrers'] : 0;

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a < $b ) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If you want *descending*, then you could do this (using the same function above):

```
usort( $array, 'sort_by_referrer_count' );
$array = array_reverse( $array );
```

Comment: Now I see what you did... It worked... Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I find to do it is by creating a new array with the `number_of_reffers` as the key. Then sort the new array with either `ksort()` or `krsort()`. This in the end leaves the original array intact. Otherwise creating the original array in the intended format would be better.

```
<?php
// original array
$array = array(
    array('refferrer' => 'http://google.com/', 'number_of_reffers' => '15'),
    array('refferrer' => 'https://facebook.com/', 'number_of_reffers' => '22'),
    array('refferrer' => 'none', 'number_of_reffers' => '74'),
    array('refferrer' => 'http://findy.com/', 'number_of_reffers' => '6')
);

$foo = array(); // new empty array

// loop through $array, assign the number_of_reffers as the key for the refferrer
foreach ($array as $key => $bar) {
    $foo[$bar['number_of_reffers']] = $bar['refferrer'];
}

/* 
    new array will be:
    array(
        '15' => 'http://google.com/',
        '22' => 'https://facebook.com/'
        etc .....
    )
*/


// use Ksort / Krsort to sort the key asc or desc
ksort($foo); // ascending order
#krsort($foo); // descending order

die('<pre>'.print_r($foo, true).'</pre>'); // pretty printing of sorted array
?>
```

**As a function ....**

```
<?php

Function Referrer_sort($array, $asc = true) {

    IF (!is_array($array)) { return 'not an array'; }

    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result[$value['number_of_reffers']] = $value['refferrer'];
    }

    switch ($asc) {
        case false: krsort($result); return $result;
        default: ksort($result); return $result;
    }

}

$foo_asc = Referrer_sort($array);
$foo_desc = Referrer_sort($array, false);

die('<pre>Ascending:<br>'.print_r($foo_asc, true).'<br>Descending:<br>'.print_r($foo_desc, true).'</pre>');

?>
```

**Changing the original array**

Modifying the original array by changing the index key with the value of `number_of_reffers`.

```
<?php

Function Rebuild_Referrer_sort($array, $asc = true) {

    IF (!is_array($array)) { return 'not an array'; }

    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result[$value['number_of_reffers']] = array('refferrer' => $value['refferrer'], 'number_of_reffers' => $value['number_of_reffers']);
    }

    switch ($asc) {
        case false: krsort($result); return $result;
        default: ksort($result); return $result;
    }

}


$foo_asc = Rebuild_Referrer_sort($array);
$foo_desc = Rebuild_Referrer_sort($array, false);

die('<pre>Ascending:<br>'.print_r($foo_asc, true).'<br>Descending:<br>'.print_r($foo_desc, true).'</pre>');

/**
  Returns:

Ascending:
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => http://findy.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 6
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => http://google.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 15
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => https://facebook.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 22
        )

    [74] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => none
            [number_of_reffers] => 74
        )

)

Descending:
Array
(
    [74] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => none
            [number_of_reffers] => 74
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => https://facebook.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 22
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => http://google.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 15
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [refferrer] => http://findy.com/
            [number_of_reffers] => 6
        )

)
*/

?>
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: updated as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$my_array;

//Sort Acceding 
usort($my_array, create_function('$a,$b', 'return (Int)$a["number_of_reffers"]-(Int)$b["number_of_reffers"];'));

//Or sort Descending
usort($my_array, create_function('$a,$b', 'return (Int)$b["number_of_reffers"]-(Int)$a["number_of_reffers"];'));
```